# Get one element from simplecart.js to JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, simplecart

just a simple question about *simplecart.js*. Is it possible to get one element such as *name* from simplecart.js into label/table at JSP web? And if anyone have the example, please let me know, i'm beginner about JS so i don't really know how to read it. Thank you.